# fieldset align fields in a div to the right

Tags: css, fieldset

I am trying to align 2 fields in my fieldset Number2 and Date of Aprobation in the div with class container2, but It fails, I want these fields at the same level of Number and Date, and I want it to the righ, but I am having troubles.
Here's the jsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ex5g/

Here is the part

```
  <div class="container2"> 
                    <label for="txtusuario">Number2:</label>
                    <input type="text" size="8" id="txtusuario" name="txtusuario" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top"/>
                    <br>
                    <br>


                    <label for="txtpass">Date of Aprobation:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom ui-corner-top"/>

                </div>
```

Thanks! Help please

Comment: What are you trying to do with the accesskey attribute? Using letters will get in the way of screen reader shortcuts I think, and having an identical key repeated seems strange.

Comment: I just copy form somewhere on the internet